# Switching bits in each nibble of an int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How can I switch the 0th and 3rd bits of each nibble in an integer using only bit operations (no control structures)? What kind of masks do I need to create in order to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated. For example, 8(1000) become 1(0001).

```
/* 
 * SwitchBits(0) = 0
 * SwitchBits(8) = 1
 * SwitchBits(0x812) = 0x182
 * SwitchBits(0x12345678) = 0x82a4c6e1
 * Legal Operations: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 */
int SwitchBits(int n) { 

}
```

Comment: Check [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html); I'm not sure the answer's there, but it is the first place to look.

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: `SwitchBits(0x812)` should be `0x112`, unless you're switching bits 3 and 0 in each *nibble*, not each *byte*. (Similarly, `SwitchBits(0x12345678)` should be `0x12345671`.)

Comment: @Thanatos my bad,it's each nibble

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static uint32_t SwitchBits(uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t bit0_mask = 0x11111111;
    uint32_t bit3_mask = 0x88888888;
    uint32_t v_bit0 = n & bit0_mask;
    uint32_t v_bit3 = n & bit3_mask;
    n &= ~(bit0_mask | bit3_mask);
    n |= (v_bit0 << 3) | (v_bit3 >> 3);
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint32_t i_values[] = { 0, 8, 0x812, 0x12345678, 0x9ABCDEF0 };
    uint32_t o_values[] = { 0, 1, 0x182, 0x82A4C6E1, 0x93B5D7F0 };
    enum { N_VALUES = sizeof(o_values) / sizeof(o_values[0]) };

    for (int i = 0; i < N_VALUES; i++)
    {
        printf("0x%.8" PRIX32 " => 0x%.8" PRIX32 " (vs 0x%.8" PRIX32 ")\n",
                i_values[i], SwitchBits(i_values[i]), o_values[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x00000000 => 0x00000000 (vs 0x00000000)
0x00000008 => 0x00000001 (vs 0x00000001)
0x00000812 => 0x00000182 (vs 0x00000182)
0x12345678 => 0x82A4C6E1 (vs 0x82A4C6E1)
0x9ABCDEF0 => 0x93B5D7F0 (vs 0x93B5D7F0)
```

Note the use of `uint32_t` to avoid undefined behaviour with sign bits in signed integers.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a bit, you can mask it out using AND. To get the lowest bit, for example:

```
x & 0x01
```

Think about how AND works: both bits must be set. Since we're ANDing with 1, all bits except the first must be 0, because they're 0 in 0x01. The lowest bit will be either 0 or 1, depending on what's in `x`; said differently, the lowest bit will be the lowest bit in `x`, which is what we want. Visually:

```
    x = abcd
AND 1 = 0001
    --------
        000d
```

(where `abcd` represent the bits in those slots; we don't know what they are)

To move it to bit 3's position, just shift it:

```
(x & 0x01) << 3
```

Visually, again:

```
x & 0x01 = 000d
    << 3
    -----------
           d000
```

To add it in, first, we need to clear out that spot in `x` for our bit. We use AND again:

```
x & ~0x08
```

Here, we invert `0x08` (which is 1000 in binary): this means all bits *except* bit 3 are set, and when we AND that with `x`, we get `x` except for that bit.

Visually,

```
 0x08 = 1000
(invert)
-----------
        0111
AND x = abcd
------------
        0bcd
```

Combine with OR:

```
(x & ~0x08) | ((x & 0x01) << 3)
```

Visually,

```
          x & ~0x08 = 0bcd
| ((x & 0x01) << 3) = d000
--------------------------
                      dbcd
```

Now, this only moves bit 0 to bit 3, and just overwrites bit 3. We still need to do bit 3 → 0. That's simply another:

```
x & 0x08 >> 3
```

And we need to clear out its spot:

```
x & ~0x01
```

We can combine the two clearing pieces:

```
x & ~0x09
```

And then:

```
(x & ~0x09) | ((x & 0x01) << 3) | ((x & 0x08) >> 3)
```

That of course handles only the lowest nibble. I'll leave the others as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code . Here you should know bitwise operator to implement and correct position to place.Also needs to aware of maintenance ,shifting and toggling basic properties.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #define BITS_SWAP(x) x=(((x & 0x88888888)>>3) | ((x & 0x11111111)<<3)) | ((x & ~ (0x88888888 | 0x11111111)))

 int main()
 {
    int data=0;
    printf("enter the data in hex=0x");
    scanf("%x",&data);
    printf("bits=%x",BITS_SWAP(data));
    return 0;
 }
```

OP

vinay@vinay-VirtualBox:~/c_skill$ ./a.out

enter the data in `hex=0x1`

`bits=8`

vinay@vinay-VirtualBox:~/c_skill$ ./a.out

enter the data in `hex=0x812`
`bits=182`

vinay@vinay-VirtualBox:~/c_skill$ ./a.out

enter the data in `hex=0x12345678`
`bits=82a4c6e1`

vinay@vinay-VirtualBox:~/c_skill$

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the low bits to the high bits and mask out the resulting bits.
2. Move the high bits to the low bits and mask out the resulting bits.
3. Mask out all bits that have not been moved.
4. Combine the results with ORs.

Code:

```
unsigned SwitchBits(unsigned n) {
  return ((n << 3) & 0x88888888) | ((n >> 3) & 0x11111111) | (n & 0x66666666);
}
```

Alternativly, if you would like to be very clever. It can be done with two fewer operations, though this may not actually be faster due to some of the dependicies between instrutions.

1. Move the high bits to align with the low bits
2. XOR recording a `0` in the low bit if high an low bits are the same, and a `1` if they are different.
3. From this, mask out only the low bit of each nibble.
4. From this, multiply by `9`, this will keep the low bit as is, and also copy it to the high bit.
5. From this, XOR with the original value. in the case that the high and low bit are the same, no change will correctly occure. In the case they are different, they will be effectivly exchanged.

Code:

```
unsigned SwitchBits(unsigned n) {
  return ((((n >> 3) ^ n) & 0x11111111) * 0x9) ^ n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant of the xor swap:

```
uint32_t switch_bits(uint32_t a){
  static const mask = 0x11111111;
  a ^= (a & mask) << 3;
  a ^= (a >> 3) & mask;
  a ^= (a & mask) << 3;
  return a;
}
```