# Reducing the number of operations

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a function to switch the 0th and 3rd bit of each hex digit, but it uses 26 ops. I just want to reduce it to 1 to 25 operations. Only using bitwise operation ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

```
int swap30(int x) {
    int m = 0b10001000 << 24;
    int m1 = 0b10001000 << 16;
    int m2 = 0b10001000 << 8;
    int m3 = 0b10001000;
    int mask1 = m | m1 | m2 | m3;

    int z = 0b01100110 << 24;
    int z1 = 0b01100110 << 16;
    int z2 = 0b01100110 << 8;
    int z3 = 0b01100110;
    int mask2 = z | z1 | z2 | z3;

    int y = 0b00010001 << 24;
    int y1 = 0b00010001 << 16;
    int y2 = 0b00010001 << 8;
    int y3 = 0b00010001;
    int mask3 = y | y1 | y2 | y3;

    int three = x & mask1;
    int stable = x & mask2;
    int one = x & mask3;
    int final2 = ((three >> 3) & mask3) | stable | (one << 3);
    return final2;
}
```

Comment: This should rather be on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The compiler will probably pre-compute `mask1`, `mask2`, and `mask3`, so you won't incur those hits at runtime.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Why only reduce by one op?

Comment: I posted on codereview before but they don't like the question either.

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140613/switching-bits-in-each-nibble-of-an-int/22150902#22150902
However I copy pasted my answer from my own answer on that post.

Answer (score 3):

```
return (x & 0x66666666) | ((x >> 3) & 0x11111111) | ((x & 0x11111111) << 3);
```

Comment: Elegant and effective.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the low bits to the high bits and mask out the resulting bits.
2. Move the high bits to the low bits and mask out the resulting bits.
3. Mask out all bits that have not been moved.
4. Combine the results with ORs.

Code:

```
unsigned SwitchBits(unsigned n) {
  return ((n << 3) & 0x88888888) | ((n >> 3) & 0x11111111) | (n & 0x66666666);
}
```

Alternativly, if you would like to be very clever. It can be done with two fewer operations, though this may not actually be faster due to some of the dependicies between instrutions.

1. Move the high bits to align with the low bits
2. XOR recording a `0` in the low bit if high an low bits are the same, and a `1` if they are different.
3. From this, mask out only the low bit of each nibble.
4. From this, multiply by `9`, this will keep the low bit as is, and also copy it to the high bit.
5. From this, XOR with the original value. in the case that the high and low bit are the same, no change will correctly occure. In the case they are different, they will be effectivly exchanged.

Code:

```
unsigned SwitchBits(unsigned n) {
  return ((((n >> 3) ^ n) & 0x11111111) * 0x9) ^ n;
}
```